# Can things be unlocked in seeded runs?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I noticed after getting a seed from my friend, ands beating the boss rush (for the first time with cain) I didn't unlock anything. Also I had a seeded run to get Guppy, but that also didn't unlock anything. Do seeded runs count towards anything? Do donation machines show up on seeded runs, and if so, do donations made on seeded runs count?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you enter a seed, you will not be able to earn achievements or unlock items during that run in most cases but some seeds such as "qwop qwop" will still enable achievements while being a consistent seed. There is also no donation machine in the shop (but shop upgrades from previous runs still make more items available).

This is shown by the no achievement icon:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/pnb9CYz.png]

Comment: So that's what that is. I was wondering what that icon meant.

Comment: "but shop upgrades from previous runs still make more items available" - does this mean that two runs with same seed can be different, for example by having more items to choose in shop?

Comment: @Asunez: That statement would also mean that players who have unlocked more items have an edge on leaderboards.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, seeded runs don't unlock anything. They also do not have a donation machine available, so you can't donate (or steal money from the donation machine by blowing it up).

Answer (score -3):

There is a exploit where you can unlock things on a seeded runs. I'm not sure if it still works, but here's the process:

1. Put in seed
2. Exit back to where you have to select a game save
3. Pick a Character and voila! A seeded run and you can unlock things.

Comment: You should really describe the exploit, if you know it. Otherwise this isn't actualy a very complete answer.

Comment: ok, not sure if it still works... 1) put in seed 2) exit back to where you have to select a game save 3) pick and Character  and vela seeded run and you can unlock things

Comment: i don't rly care... ok?