# I can't seem to unlock the Womb

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I bet Mom once with Lazarus. I beat Mom again with Azazel and the game ended there and I didn't unlock the Womb. I also collected 60 coins and didn't unlock Cain. I'd better mention that both times I beat Mom I had typed in seeds I saw from streamers/youtubers.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/197536/87579

Answer (score 9):

Having used seeds is exactly your problem. You can't unlock anything when using seeds.